# Ethernet works during install, but after booting neither eth0 or wlan0 appear

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, ethernet

First time I tried to install 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 1500, the wi-fi didn't work to download updates while installing. Upon first boot, it still didn't work so I plugged in the ethernet cable. Still didn't work. Reinstalled with cable plugged in and it recognized it so it and could download everything fine. Upon first boot, it said 'disconnected' and no ethernet was found. Running "ifconfig -a" only shows lo. There is no eth0 and no wlan0. What's going on?? Tried using the live CD and then ethernet works and eth0 shows up, but even installing from there doesn't solve the issue. Clearly it's not a hardware thing. Also the wi-fi switch is enabled as it can find bluetooth, but the wireless doesn't work either. I also tried 13.10, but that has the same problems. I can't just run Ubuntu off the live CD all the time! Any ideas?

Edit:
`lspci -nn|grep 0280`

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b44
```

Your ethernet should now be working. Hook it up and continue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After a reboot, you should be all set.

Comment: First line worked fine, but `sudo modprobe b44` is just sitting at the terminal, blinking as if it is looking for more input.

Comment: Can you reboot and show us: lspci -nn | grep 0200.

Comment: 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)

Comment: The driver for your ethernet is indeed b44 as I suspected. Did it load automatically after the reboot? Check: lsmod | grep b4 Is the ethernet working?

Comment: Yes! The ethernet worked upon reboot so I ran the last 2 lines and then restarted again. Wireless works now too. Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 I had the exact same problem (Dell Vostro 1500)  with Ubuntu 16.10.  Worked fine from the Live USB but had no eth0 after installing.  Running the first two commands had the exact same result ...looked like it didn't work, but after rebooting, the wired connection works! Thanks!